# Test custom DateUtilClass with Calendar.getInstance() without DependencyInjection

Tags: java, testing, junit, calendar, mocking

Consider the following class:

```
public class DateUtils {

    public static Date get31OfDecember2YearsAgo() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int year2YearsAgo = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 2;
        calendar.set(year2YearsAgo, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

Do you have any clue how I could test this code? I was thinking of a DateProvider, which I could inject and mock it in the tests, but since i have no dependency Injection available...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could refactor the class as follows:

```
public class DateUtils {

  public static Date get31OfDecember2YearsAgo() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date()); // This line is surely redundant?
    return get31OfDecember2YearsAgo(calendar);
  }

  static Date get31OfDecember2YearsAgo(Calendar calendar) {        
    int year2YearsAgo = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 2;
    calendar.set(year2YearsAgo, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);
    return calendar.getTime();
  }
}
```

This would allow you to test the package-private variant and use some known values to check for the correct result.

Comment: Ok, and how do I assert the outcome of my method?

Comment: @Chris311 You just create a known `Calendar`/`Date` pair and do `assertEquals(expectedDate, DateUtils.get31OfDecember2YearsAgo(yourCalendar))`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is hard-coded to use `Calendar` and `Date`, so you cannot really test it as it is.  Then again, `public static` methods are generally not meant to be tested; instead, they are supposed to be so simple that you can just look at them and determine whether they are correct or not.

I would strongly encourage you to throw away this `get31ofDecember2YearsAgo()` method, along with the entire `DateUtils` class, and refactor your entire system to start using a properly designed instantiatable class for date and time utilities.  When doing so, make use of the latest java 8 time classes, or, if you are unlucky enough to have to work with some version of java prior to 8, then at least use the joda time library.

Be sure to never use the ill-conceived `Instant.now()` method anywhere; instead, create an interface which provides the current time, so that you can properly mock it for testing purposes.

***EDIT***

Here, from a project I am working on:

```
import java.time.*;

/**
 * Provides the notion of current time. Necessary, because without it, 
 * classes that deal with the current time cannot be tested.
 *
 * @author Michael Belivanakis (michael.gr)
 */
public interface TimekeepingDomain
{
    /**
     * Gets the current {@link Instant}.  (UTC, of course.)
     *
     * @return the current {@link Instant}.
     */
    Instant getCurrentInstant();

    /**
     * Gets the system {@link ZoneId}.
     *
     * @return the system {@link ZoneId}.
     */
    ZoneId getSystemZoneId();

    /**
     * Sleeps until the given {@link Instant}.
     *
     * Returns immediately if the given {@link Instant} is in the past.
     *
     * @param instant the {@link Instant} to sleep until.
     */
    void sleepUntil( Instant instant ) throws InterruptedException;

    /**
     * Sleeps for the given {@link Duration}.
     *
     * Returns immediately if the given {@link Duration} is negative.
     *
     * @param duration the {@link Duration} to sleep for.
     */
    void sleepFor( Duration duration ) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

A "real" timekeeping domain implementation:

```
final TimekeepingDomain timekeepingDomain = new TimekeepingDomain()
{
    @Override
    public Instant getCurrentInstant()
    {
        return Instant.now();
    }

    @Override
    public ZoneId getSystemZoneId()
    {
        return ZoneId.systemDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public void sleepUntil( Instant instant ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        sleepFor( Duration.between( Instant.now(), instant ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void sleepFor( Duration duration ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        if( duration.isNegative() )
            return;
        long milliseconds = duration.toMillis();
        Thread.sleep( milliseconds );
    }
};
```

A "fake" timekeeping domain implmentation:

```
import java.time.*;

/**
 * Fake {@link TimekeepingDomain} for testing.
 *
 * @author Michael Belivanakis (michael.gr)
 */
class FakeTimekeepingDomain implements TimekeepingDomain
{
    private Instant currentInstant;

    FakeTimekeepingDomain( Instant startTime )
    {
        currentInstant = startTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Instant getCurrentInstant()
    {
        currentInstant = currentInstant.plusMillis( 1L );
        return currentInstant;
    }

    @Override
    public ZoneId getSystemZoneId()
    {
        return ZoneOffset.UTC;
    }

    @Override
    public void sleepUntil( Instant instant )
    {
        if( instant.isAfter( currentInstant ) )
            currentInstant = instant;
    }

    @Override
    public void sleepFor( Duration duration )
    {
        if( !duration.isNegative() )
            currentInstant = currentInstant.plus( duration );
    }
}
```

Instantiated as follows:

```
TimekeepingDomain timekeepingDomain = 
        new FakeTimekeepingDomain( Instant.parse( "2014-08-11T10:15:30.00Z" ) );
```

So what happens then is that your `calculateSomethingRelativeToNow()` method becomes non-static and the class which contains it is passed a `TimekeepingDomain` as a constructor parameter, so that your method can invoke that interface in order to get (what you want it to think of as) the current time.

In your production rig, you pass your class a reference to a real implementation of `TimekeepingDomain` and everything works as before.

In your test rig, you can pass your class an instance of `FakeTimekeepingDomain` which has been instantiated to pretend that the 'current' time is some fixed time, (in the past, or the future, it does not matter,) so that you can check the result of your method to see that it is in fact what it is expected to be.  You can try with various fixed times, to check for various results.

This is, in essence, dependency injection done manually, without the use of some heavy framework like `Spring` to achieve it.

Comment: I think this is a bit of an overhead.

Comment: Trust me, testability is usually well worth the overhead. But unless you have thrown a profiler on your system which has in fact identified your time utilities as being a performance bottleneck, then this is not even an overhead worth speaking of.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such a properly designed instantiatable class for date and time utilities? I tried something, but it didn't felt quite good.